# Apps Scripts OAuth2 authorization using gapi from inside HtmlService

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to be OAuth2-authorized by using the gapi library from inside an HtmlService project. I've got my CLIENT_ID from the console and I've set up the "Authorized Javascript Origins" with all of what I could think about like "https://script.google.com", "https://script.googleusercontent.com", etc, but I always end with an "origin mismatch" error.

This is the code I'm using from inside the html javascript code.

```
function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'scope': SCOPES,
    'immediate': false
  }, handleAuthResult);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you double checked and followed what was mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js#troubleshooting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the origin you need launch your webapp. Right click and click `Inspect`.  This should open Devtools. Click on the `Elements` tab. Look for the iframe with the id="sandboxFrame". The source the that iframe in your webapp origin. It will look like:

[image: webapp origin as seeen in devtools]

When you add it to your credentials just add the domain part leaving off the endpoint.

> https://n-rilyfaex6q3..iimkn7ufgvlphhi2..l3l73y-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com

Comment: n-***-script.googleusercontent.com  off the top of my head I don't remember is you add https://